# How to use Font Awesome offline in SASS

Tags: sass, font-awesome

I recently started using SASS and right now I need Font Awesome for one of my project but I want to use it offline. I know that I could simply use CDN (as I did) but I just don't know how to use it offline so it's pretty annoying :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you just download the resources, add the .js/css-links to your .html and use the icons ;-)

It's all described on their [website](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js) - but the choice of options (CSS or SVG) might make it look more difficult than it is...